# Validar modelos con mongoose nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo mi modelo user.

```
// models/user.js
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema=new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:"Es necesario un nombre",
        maxlength:[10,"Nombre muy largo max 10"]
    },
    lastName:{
        type:String,
        required:"Es necesario el apellido",
        maxlength:[10,"Apellido muy largo"]
    },
    userName:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        require:"Es necesario un username",
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        require:"Es necesario un password",
        validate:{
            validator:function(pass){
                    if( this.password_confirmation!=undefined)
                        return this.password_confirmation==pass;
                    else{
                        return true;
                    }
            },
            message:"Las contraseñas son diferentes"
        }
    },
    email:{
    type:String,
    require:"Es necesario un email"
    }
})

userSchema.virtual("password_confirmation").get(function(){
    return this.p_c
}).set(function(password){
    this.p_c=password;
})

var User=mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
module.exports=User;
```

Un endpoint para logearme.

```
//  routes/user.js
router.route("/login").get(login.login_get).post(login.login_post);
```

// login_post

```
var login_post=function(req,res,next){

    if(!req.body.password || !req.body.userName){
        res.send("Error");
    }

    User.findOne({userName:req.body.userName,password:req.body.password},function(err,us){
        if(err)console.log(String(err));
        console.log("Usuario encontra",us);
        res.send(us);
    });

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente , validar desde el modelo antes de entrar a User.findOne ,por ejemplo algo asi.

```
var user=new User(req.body,function(err){
   if(err)res.send("Error",String(err));
});

User.findOne({userName:user.userName,password:user.password},function(err,us){
        if(err)console.log(String(err));
        console.log("Usuario encontra",us);
        res.send(us);
    });
```

para evitar usar esto y validar desde el modelo.

```
  if(!req.body.password || !req.body.userName){
            res.send("Error");
        }
```

o sino se puede de esa manera tal vez algo asi.

```
    var validate=function(model,next){
    if(//NO SE QUE IRIA PARA VALIDAR EL MODELO//){}
    next("//Algo como los errores del modelo model.err//);    
    }   

   var user=new User(req.body);
   validate(user,function(err){
       if(err){
            console.log(String(err));
            res.send("Hubo un error validando los datos",err);
        }
}
```

}

Esto es para poder buscar usuarios , ya que para crear pues no es necesario hacer algo adicional , pues si me bota los errores que he puesto.

Ya que al hacer

```
User.findOne({userName:req.body.userName,password:req.body.password},function(err,us){
        if(err)console.log(String(err));
        console.log("Usuario encontra",us);
        res.send(us);
    });
```

sin la validación arroja solo que no encontro al usuario , y ningun error si por ejemplo no pongo password.

**Para md**

No sabia lo de DTO, en cuando a validate pinta bien , entonces si deberia crear un DTO schema  en casos concretos , pero a lo que iba  es lo siguiente ,lo que estaba haciendo en mis ejemplos era para traer el pull de errores , que definia en el modelo ya que por ejemplo si ponia algo como

```
User.create(req.body,function(err,us){
if(err) console.log(String(err)); 
console.log(us);
});
```

Este si me trae el conjunto de errores , por ejemlo si contraseñas no coinciden , o falta llenar un campo, algo asi queria hacer para el findOne , pero este no me trae el pull de errores (los definidos en userSchema) para mostrarlos en un toast, sino mas bien no detecta ningun error por lo tanto no me retorna nada.

Con lo que me pones de crear un DTO lo podria hacer , pero la cuestion es que queria minimar el codigo que ponia , además de las librerias,por eso mi consulta.

Si en los codigos de respuesta se me fue ,aún me falta optimizar mejor el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente , validar desde el modelo antes de entrar a User.findOne ,por ejemplo algo asi.
>
> `var user=new User(req.body,function(err){
>      if(err)res.send("Error",String(err));
>   });`

Aquí una diferencia importante: Normalmente el objeto/modelo que transportas por la red es diferente del que almacenas en la base. Por ejemplo, nunca enviarias el password del usuario cuando le respondes por motivos de seguridad, tampoco permitiras que cambie algunas propiedades del registro, como un id que lo relaciona con otra entidad, etc.

Solemos llamar a los objetos que almacenamos en la base como el MODELO, y a los objeto que usamos para transferir datos entre nodos, el DTO (o Data Transfer Object).

Ahora, en Javascript por su dinamismo, no siempre hace falta crear un modelo separado (el modelo primario no servira pues requiere name, lastName, etc). Hay que evaluarlo en cada caso. Este caso no parece necesario, por ser dos campos y fácil de validar.

Alternativamente, una opción mas liviana que crear un Schema para UserDTO seria usar alguna librería liviana de validación de esquemas como [indicative](http://indicative.adonisjs.com/).

Por cierto, en el código que nos mostraste no hay nada para cuando el usuario no existe en la base o la clave no coincide (quizá era un ejemplo simplificado, pero lo he tenido en cuenta en el ejemplo)

Otro cambio que te recomiendo realices es utilizar los códigos de respuesta apropiados osea 500, 401 y 400 dependiendo del caso (ver en el código)

```
const indicative = require('indicative')

const userLoginDTOschema = {
  userName: 'required',
  password: 'required'
}

var login_post = function(req, res, next) {
  indicative.validate(req.body, userLoginDTOschema)
    .then(function() {
      // validation passed
      User.findOne({
          userName: req.body.userName,
          password: req.body.password
        },
        function(err, us) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(String(err));
            // en viejas versiones es send(500)
            res.sendStatus(500); // Internal Server Error
          }
          if (us) { 
            console.log("Usuario encontrado", us);
            res.send(us); // Ojo!!! aqui te faltaria filtrar el password y demas datos sensibles.
          } else {
            console.log("Usuario no encontrado", us);
            res.sendStatus(401); // Unauthorized
          }
        });
    }).catch(function(errors) {
      // validation failed
      res.sendStatus(400); // Bad Request
    })
}
```

Salu2

## EDICION:

Entiendo lo que dices en tu edicion: Quiza el ejemplo de LOGIN no es el mejor caso pues nunca quieres informar del error exacto, por motivos de seguridad. Pero como esto es aplicable a cualquier entidad te comento que indicative tiene otro metodo

```
var errores = indicative.validateAll(data, rules)
```

El cual retorna un arreglo con la lista de errores/violaciones del esquema dado. Por lo que te sirve para informar.

Es tu elección, entiendo que agregar otra librería es una decisión complicada por muchas razones, y esta es solo una alternativa.

A mi gusto es una buena alternativa a tu problema general, te permite hacer todo tipo de validaciones, personalizar los mensajes de error, usar templates y argumentar los mensajes de error, te permite sanear (aka sanitizar) los datos de entrada y la documentación se basa en ejemplos y la puedes leer en 15-20 minutos.

Comment: Amigo actualice el post.

Comment: Hey @KevinAB te deje otros comentarios Salu2!!

Comment: Entiendo , lo revisaré con mas detalle , gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: md , creo que tiens razon para login no seria necesario informar del error  exacto, pero si en otros casos , además si bien cierto a pesar que no se necesite informar en la parte del usuario , me podría servir para logs , y estadistica por poner un ejemplo.